# Influencing Solr Spellcheck

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

For an ecommerce website, with Solr for search, we are using standard spellcheck component and it works fine for some cases but not for others. This questions is about to understand how it works in the background and how do I improve it..

for ex:
I have a few products with a 'bracelet' in its name. And when I search for wrongly spelled term like 'brecelet' or 'bracelat' or 'braselet' or 'brecelat' it corrects it as 'bracelet' but not with a term 'breclate'.

Why it doesn't work for last term and how can I influence it.

**Update:**
spellcheck configurations:

```
<field name="SpellContent" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" required="false" />
```

We have above field in which we copy the Name field.

```
 <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

And spellcheck as:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">SpellContent</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
    </lst>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
      <str name="field">SpellContent</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">false</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>     
    </lst>

  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: Could you share your part of solrconfig.xml related to spellcheck/

Comment: @Mysterion I updated question with details you requested